# How to bring up an hourly graph for a specified period (rather than only "Last Hour") in Ganglia

Tags: graphical-user-interface, ganglia

Sorry if this is a silly question but I can't find a way to make Ganglia display an hourly graph of a specified time.

How do I do this? The version of my Ganglia Web Frontend is 3.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ganglia web version that ships with your distribution doesn't have this feature. You have to show the graphs in last day and zoom in to an area of interest.

However, you can do it by using the [`ganglia-web`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganglia/files/ganglia-web/) version from the homepage:

[image]

[image]

Also, don't miss some important other features like: Aggregate graphs, Compare Host, ...
See [document](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/ganglia-web-2) fore more details.